# Unable to get the current password in Jhipster for user entity

Tags: angular, spring-boot, passwords, jhipster

I am working on jhipster.

I am unable to get the current password in jhipster and Spring.

The user class I get it doesn't have a password attribute.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to read passwords in client as they are hashed on server, this is done this way for security reasons. In client you can only submit a new password or send the old one for being hashed and compared with the hash of the one stored in database.

Comment: For security reason , i need to compare the current password with the password typed by user , after this ,  if they are equal i will move to change password .

Comment: Then do as I explained: compare hashes on server. Modify changePassword method in UserService.java